# MySQL Replication Relay for Peer-to-peer replication for Multi-master replications

Tags: mysql, transactional-replication, merge-replication, master-slave-replication, master-master-replication

Any one knows about MySQL Replication Relay for Peer-to-Peer Replication for Multi-master replications?

Please share if you know anything with example and syntax for multiple clients with as masters replications in MySQL.

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: i need to create one web app with multi master replication database connectivity.

Comment: Still unclear -- Why multi-master?  Will there be Slaves?  You mentioned Relays, but that is not a necessary part of the system.  Etc.

Comment: a live slaves are also for masters of them slaves. e.g. server-A is a master and Server-B is a slave of Server-A but Server-B is also master of Server-C.

Comment: "A -> B -> C" is not considered "multi-master".  A is a Master, B is a Relay (acting both as a Master and a Slave), and C is a Slave.  There are only a few useful cases for such; can you elaborate on what the goal is of the configuration?  Perhaps from that, you could start a new Question.  (Getting this question off Hold is hard.)

Answer (score 1):

(The question is much too broad.  So, I will give only a broad explanation of Master, Slave, and Relay.)

A server can be a Master, a Slave, or both.

Dual-Master (a form of multi-master) has both servers being both Master and Slave.  By having `server_id` different for the two servers, Replication is smart enough not to get into a loop.

In a multi-master setup, one *can* write to any Master.  There are many caveats one needs to be aware of.

A "Relay" server acts as a Slave to receive data from a Master, then passes it on to Slave(s).

In a Master-Slave or Master-Relay-Slave setup, one should write only to the Master.  Writing to a Relay or Slave is asking for trouble.

Clients can talk to any MySQL server; it does not matter whether they are Master or Slave or both.  However, typically one controls which server to talk to -- in order to control load balancing, HA, etc.

Galera and InnoDB Cluster / Group Replication are tools to make Multi-Master configurations more manageable.

Comment: will you please send me steps for multi master replication creation and how to use?

Comment: Do not use Multi-Master, it is fraught with issues of duplicate keys, hung replication, difficulties in recovery, etc.